# How to enable RSS on ETH_RSS_VXLAN or ETH_RSS_GENEVE for a DPDK application?

Tags: hash, dpdk

I am trying to find out what are parameters used to calculate RSS hash when tunnelled RSS hash offloads are used, such as **ETH_RSS_VXLAN** or **ETH_RSS_GENEVE**. Target is to distribute the incoming VXLAN traffic based on VNI rather than outer IP or UDP port number in DPDK.

- DPDK version: 20.11.1
- NIC: Mellanox ConnectX-5, firmware version 16.30.1004

I have been testing out the different RSS hash using the inner IP fields to calculate the hash. Settings of setting done: [RSS Setting inside the L3FWD application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm17I.png)

[EDIT-1 based on comment conversation]

1. the NIC card I am using does not support the **ETH_RSS_VXLAN** or other tunnel RSS offloads, I am unable to test it.
2. I am not making use of RTE_FLOW since I am using sample l3fwd example application.

Comment: please update your ticket with NIC, Firmware, code snippet for RSS, and RTE_FLOW is used or not?

Comment: Added the information requested.

Comment: as per your new update `As the NIC card I am using does not support the ETH_RSS_VXLAN or other tunnel RSS offloads,`. Hence what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: because as per PMD support MLX5_EXPANSION_OUTER_IPV4_UDP, MLX5_EXPANSION_OUTER_IPV6_UDP, MLX5_EXPANSION_VXLAN and MLX5_EXPANSION_VXLAN_GPE is supported under RTE_FLOW for encap and decap VxLAN. RSS is only enabled for ETH_RSS_NONFRAG_IPV6_UDP or ETH_RSS_NONFRAG_IPV6_UDP for outer header. http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/mlx5.html talks about RSS and VxLan offloads with switch, so if you are using switch decap VXLAN, you will be getting packets with RSS on rx queue. But if the intention is to receive VXLAN packets with RSS enabled on VNI, I do not think there is option currently in DPDK 20.11

Comment: I am trying to find out that if the ETH_RSS_VXLAN were to be used on a NIC, what would be its behavior? Would it use the VNI? Would it use the the inner IP header fields or the outer IP header fields (if coupled with ETH_RSS_IP).

Comment: as shared based on MXl5 PMD and documentation there is no option for RSS on VNI fields hence the option `ETH_RSS_VXLAN` is absent. RSS default is based on outer IP, but If you need to access RSS inner IP fields after VNI, use RTE_FLOW. to enable RSS for specific (vxlan) packets.

Comment: let me know if it is clear?

Comment: It is clear that the mlx5 pmd does not have this option but I what I want to know is that if a certain NIC used this option, what would be its behavior? For example the QLogic FastLinQ PMD seems to have a reference of ETH_RSS_VXLAN in its qede_rxtx.h file, inside drivers.

Comment: QELOGIC and Thunderx has RSS for vxlan by default. Intel FVl and CVL enable these via DDP profile. But as mentioned is not the question related to MXL5? I will update the answer, please accept and upvote if it is helpful

Comment: The question I wanted to ask was never about mlx5, I just wanted general information of how it would work. Also you mentioned a DDP profile, would be great if you can shed some light on that as well.

Comment: I can update the following details what I know in the answer. But if you specific questions on DPDK based on vendor NIC. I highly recommend to open specific question and share your steps and issues. there is no generic answer for vendor specific NIC questions.

Comment: Update with the answers, if you have found it useful please accept and upvote to close the ticket.

Comment: can you please accept and upvote to close the current ticket.

Comment: Well since the original question has been changed totally, I will post a new ticket regarding what the information I actually need.

Comment: what do you mean by the original question changed? I am now confused with the words

Comment: you can check the edits and approval by tracking history, May 3 (edit is added for adding mellanox NIC and firmware) and on May 4 the formatting is done to clearly describe the current problem. As far as I can see there is no change in intention of your original question. So please either close the ticket by accept/upvote or deleting the current one.

Answer (score 0):

As per DPDK 20.11.1 and MLX5 PMD, enabling VXLAN based RSS via DPDK rte_dev_configure is not present. because the current PMD support MLX5_EXPANSION_OUTER_IPV4_UDP, MLX5_EXPANSION_OUTER_IPV6_UDP, MLX5_EXPANSION_VXLAN and MLX5_EXPANSION_VXLAN_GPE is for `RTE_FLOW` for encap and decap VxLAN for the switch. while DPDK `rte_eth_dev_configure` is **generic** API for all NIC.

So if the real intention is to distribute packets based on INNER IP, I highly recommend use **RTE_FLOW**, with flow match as OUTER-IP and UDP port numbers and action as RSS on INNER IP and port Number. But L3FWD application has to be modified for the same.

Other DPDK supported NICs also supports VNI (with varying degree);

1. NXP Qede
2. marvell thunderx
3. Intel FVL and CVL

on Intel FVL and CVL lookup can be done, followed by RSS distribution to specific queues. generic setup can be done via

1. for FVL identify NIC firmware which supports VXLAN from Intel site for your NIC.
2. using nvmupdate tool flash FVL with firmware and restart the machine.
3. Using DPDK application (example: testpmd) create 5 rxqueues
4. set flow rule as `IF traffic is tunneled with VXLAN, then use action 1) RSS for inner IP on Q1 to Q4 action 2) Decap the Tunnel header`.

refer [sample test](https://doc.dpdk.org/dts/test_plans/vxlan_test_plan.html) for more details.

note: I highly recommend opening DPDK vendor specific question, with details on the sample program, steps followed and issues faced.

Comment: I am having a hard time finding a place with some example code of how to set up my application to use the RTE_FLOW thingy so that RSS distributes packets to queues based on the inner IP headers. Do you know where I can find an example for this? This seems to be so poorly documented.